# PDEs solutions and domain mappings

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Sorry if this question is a bit vague, but is due to the fact that I have not been able to find any resource about the following problem.

Suppose we have a PDE on a spatial domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose there exists a map that maps the original domain $\Omega$ to a new domain $\tilde\Omega$. Let $u(x)$ be the solution of the PDE on the original domain, while solving the same PDE (or slightly different) on the mapped domain leads to $\tilde u(x)$. Is it reasonable to ask for the existence of a map  $\tilde u(x) \mapsto u(x)$?

Are there any resources, papers or books tackling such problem?

(Sorry again for the rough and vague mathematical formulation, but I’ve just approached the subject.)

Comment: I think this is the way large deformation elasticity problems are usually formulated. There is a "reference" and "current" configuration (domain). Perhaps it would be worth looking at works from that field?